# LoDash check if object one and two value are equal if so compare

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lodash

Can I do that better with LoDash? I want to check if the first object id is equal with the second one, if so it should add something to the first object from the second one. Here my current solution:

```
vm.forumUsers.forEach(function(user, forumIndex){
  vm.teamspeakClients.forEach(function(client, clientIndex){
    if (user.tsid === client.client_unique_identifier) {
      vm.forumUsers[forumIndex]['tsdbid']           = client.cldbid;
      vm.forumUsers[forumIndex]['tsnickname']       = client.client_nickname;
      vm.forumUsers[forumIndex]['tslastconnected']  = client.client_lastconnected;
    }
  });
});

vm.usersCollection = vm.forumUsers;
```

Comment: What's the reasoning behind choosing Lodash for this task? Is it already used in the project? Because usually filter-map-reduce are good enough for that.

Comment: Yes I'm working with LoDash for now and changed some things with it, to make all a bit more clear. 
What did you mean with filter-map-reduce? @estus

Comment: There is already a number of built-in ES5 (filter-map-reduce) and polyfilled ES6 array functions that allow to do the job in more idiomatic fashion. Some things (like Lodash `pick`) are still pretty handy, but in this particular case Lodash can't offer much, except extra footprint.

Comment: Could you please provide an example how to do that or which one is the best solution for about 500 users. @estus

Comment: It really depends on how often this piece of code runs. If it is triggered on every digest and may cause performance issues, for lengthy loops (500 is a considerable number) I would suggest to replace `forEach` with good old `for(var i = 0...` and look no further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS already offers idiomatic ways for a lot of things that Underscore/Lodash was intended for.

For ES5 it may be

```
vm.forumUsers.forEach(function(user) {
   var client = vm.teamspeakClients
  .filter(function (client) { return user.tsid === client.client_unique_identifier })
  .map(function (client) { return {
    tsdbid: client.cldbid,
    tsnickname : client.client_nickname,
    tslastconnected: client.client_lastconnected
  })[0];

  Object.assign(user, client);
});
```

It becomes even neater for ES6.

If performance is the case (it may be an issue for UI code with considerable amount of data) raw `for` loop is always the best option.

Answer (score 1):

merge user with finded clients special keys

```
var res = _.map(vm.forumUsers, function(user) {
    return _.chain(vm.teamspeakClients)
         .find({client_unique_identifier: user.tsid}) // find client
         .defaultTo({})  // set {} if client not found
         .thru(function(client) { // convert props, use _.pick to set same clients keys 
             return {
                  tsdbid: client.cldbid,
                  tsnickname: client.client_nickname,
                  tslastconnected: client.client_lastconnected
             };
         })
         .merge(user)
         .value();
})
```